# Avoid duplicate records in linq query while joining multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I have following tabes in my DB

```
TestPack { id, name, type }
Documentation { id, tp_id, date, rev }
Flushing { id, tp_id, date, rev }
```

tp_Id is the TestPack ID and is the foreign key in both Documentation and Flushing tables which means a TestPack may have 1-N Documentations and Flushings.

Now I want to query the database (using EF LINQ) to return tests packs, and all their Documentations and Flushings against one Test Pack so that I can show all this information in a single DataGrid?

Test Packs, that dont have any Documentatoin/Flushings should also show up in the result.

**Here is my query that I have written so far**

```
 internal List<TestPackRegister> GenerateReport2()
{
    var allTestPacks = Project.GetAllTestPacks();
    var allDocumentation = Project.GetAllDocoumentations();
    var allFlushings = Project.GetAllPreTestFlushings();

    var queryResult = from tp in allTestPacks

        join doc in allDocumentation on tp.id equals doc.test_pack_id.Value
        into tpDoc
        from subtpDoc in tpDoc.DefaultIfEmpty()

        join flushings in allFlushings on tp.id equals flushings.test_pack_id.Value
        into tpFlings
        from subtpflushings in tpFlings.DefaultIfEmpty()

        select new TestPackRegister
        {
            test_pack_no = tp.test_pack_no,

            Documentation_Notification = subtpDoc != null ? subtpDoc.const_notification_no : null,
            Documentation_Rev = subtpDoc != null ? subtpDoc.const_notification_no_rev : null,
            Documentation_Notification_Date = subtpDoc != null ? subtpDoc.const_notification_date : null,
            Documentation_TargetReadiness_Date = subtpDoc != null ? subtpDoc.doc_readiness_target_date : null,
            Documentation_ActualReadiness_Date = subtpDoc != null ? subtpDoc.doc_readiness_date : null,
            Documentation_Remarks = subtpDoc != null ? subtpDoc.remarks : null,

            Flushing_RFI = subtpflushings != null ? subtpflushings.RFINo : null,
            Flushing_Rev = subtpflushings != null ? subtpflushings.rfi_rev_no : null,
            Flushing_RFI_Date = subtpflushings != null && subtpflushings.rfi_date != null ? subtpflushings.rfi_date : null,
            Flushing_Planned_Date = subtpflushings != null && subtpflushings.planned_date != null ? subtpflushings.planned_date : null,
            Flushing_Actual_Date = subtpflushings != null && subtpflushings.actual_date != null ? subtpflushings.actual_date : null,
            Flushing_Acceptance_Date = subtpflushings != null && subtpflushings.acceptance_date != null ? subtpflushings.acceptance_date : null,
            Flushing_Remarks = subtpflushings != null ? subtpflushings.remarks : null,
        };

    QueryResult = queryResult.ToList();
    return QueryResult;
}
```

**And here is the result of the query**

[image]

Basically in my TestPack table, I have 2 testPacks.
Test Pack 1 has 2 Documentations and 2 Flushing records while Test Pack 2 has only 1 Documentation and 1 Flushing record.
So my concern here is that TestPack # 1 is showing four rows, Should not it be showing two rows? because the test pack has 2 flushings and 2 documentation for 1 testPack. so all of them should appear in 2 rows? Why they are appearing as four rows? And how can I correct this behavior?

Comment: I would expect that query to return four items.  In the case of test pack 1 you joined `allTestPacks` to `allDocumentation` which would result in 2 items in `tpDoc`.  You then joined `tpDoc` on `allFlushings`; `allFlushings` has two items for test pack 1; 2 times 2 is 4.  Do Flushing and Documentation have any relation to each other?  Based on your expectation that the query should only return two rows for test pack 1 I think there must be some relationship between the two; perhaps the `rev` field, or maybe both the `rev` and `date` fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck in this too. This is my approach:

```
foreach (var tp in allTestPacks)
        {
            var lstAllFlh = allFlushings.Where(m => m.TpID == tp.IDTP).ToList();
            var lstAllDoc = allDocumentation.Where(m => m.TpID == tp.IDTP).ToList();
            foreach (var flh in lstAllFlh)
                lstResult.Add(new { TPID = tp.IDTP, TPName = tp.Value, DocName = lstAllDoc.Skip(lstAllFlh.FindIndex(f => f == flh) % lstAllDoc.Count).First().Value, FlushName = flh.Value });
        }
```